# ListView doesnt respond until scrolled

Tags: android, android-listview

In My application  `ListView` items won't respond unless I scroll down a bit. After I scroll down, and then scroll up back to the beginning, they start responding. What could possibly cause such behavior?

Comment: Could you show us some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code the only assumption that I can make is that you are having performance issues.  I would start looking at your UI performance with  [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html).  If that doesn't tell the story try using a tool like [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to see if you have something holding up your main thread.

Comment: When the UI stuck the main thread is on wait state... dont know whats going on... worked on it too much time and got nothing... i think its androids bug not mine as i did exactly what they did in their samples...

Comment: One quick thing you could look at is if you have nested views in your ListView.  They can greatly slow down the performance and give you the problems you are seeing.  The Hierarchy Viewer will also show the performance impact.